# How to exclude unwanted packages like mail and ws from from javaee-api-7?

Tags: java, jersey, tomcat7, persistence

I have a project that requires only persistence  module or persistence package of javaee api 7.jar. I want to exclude all those packages and mange this via my pom.xml as it a maven based project ? How can I achieve that ? What will my pom.xml look like ?

Comment: what do you mean "exclude all those packages?" Do you mean you only want the persistence module/persistence package from javaee api 7, but nothing else from javaee api 7?

Comment: yes.. I need to run a web project which includes several other API which conflict with javaee api 7's jar packages other than persistence. By excluding those packages manually I am able to run the project successfully , but however once I include them it throws errors. How can I exclude them while building the project using maven?

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out what packages/classes you do need
2. find the right `<dependency></dependency>` for maven for those packages
3. only put those packages from javaee 7 api in your `pom.xml`.

That's your only choice. If the JavaEE 7 api is not modular enough, then maybe you won't be able to grab only the `persistence package` without getting the other packages from JavaEE 7 api that conflict with your other API -- in which case I think you may be stuck.

I think this link may be helpful -- https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Java+EE+7+Maven+Coordinates -- about halfway down the list there is:

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>  
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks...But I did try excluding those dependencies using exclusions in my pom.xml but failed to do so as javaee api jar always included those excluded packages too